# Using an enum as generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to coordinate the completion of several async processes whose order of execution and completion time are somewhat arbitrary.  In these cases i have a built a little coordinator that looks something like this:

```
enum Conditions {
    Authentication,
    UserLoad,
    ProjectsLoad,
    BudgetLoad
 }
 class UserLoadComplete {
    conditionCount : number
    conditions : boolean[]=[]

    constructor() {
       this.conditionCount = Object.keys(Conditions).length/2;
       for (let i=0; i<this.conditionCount; i++) {
          this.conditions.push(false)
       }
    }

    markComplete(condition : Conditions) {
       this.conditions[condition]=true;
    }

    get isReady() : boolean {
       for(let satisfied of this.conditions) {
          if (!satisfied) return false;
       }
       return true;
    }

    get pendingConditions() : string[] {
        let pending : string[]=[];
        for (let i=0; i<this.conditionCount; i++) {
            if (!this.conditions[i]) {
                pending.push(Conditions[i]);
            }
        }
        return pending;
    }
```

}

This works fine, but I would like to find a way to make a generic condition checker with a declaration that looks like `class ConditionChecker<T>`where T is an enum.

Then I could create different condition checkers generically with something like:

```
 let userLoadCompleteChecker = new ConditionChecker<Conditions>()
```

Can this be done in typescript?  Right now I can't figure out how to replace `this.conditionsCount = Object.keys(Conditions).length/2` with some version of `this.conditionsCount = Object.keys(T).length/2.`

Also, it seems like getting the "getPending" method to work with a generic type var could be tricky as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type information is erased after TypeScript is transpiled into JavaScript.
Therefore, your enum, as well as the `<T>` are not part of the final JavaScript that is executed.
This means, other than e.g. in .NET, you can't do `new T()` or such.

One possible solution could be to do something like this:

```
 class SomeCondition {
    static Authentication = 'Authentication';
    static UserLoad = 'UserLoad';
    static ProjectsLoad = 'ProjectsLoad';
    static BudgetLoad = 'Authentication';
 };

 class ConditionChecker {
    conditionCount : number
    conditions : boolean[]=[]

    constructor(conditionType: Object) {
       this.conditionCount = Object.keys(conditionType).length/2;
       for (let i=0; i<this.conditionCount; i++) {
          this.conditions.push(false)
       }
    }
 ...

const checker = new ConditionChecker(SomeCondition);
```

I.e.:

- Use a class to represent the enum values
- Pass the "enum" as constructor argument